# How to create a section table view which depends on the table view data in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to create a sectioned table view. Using XML parsing, i got the datas and displayed in the table view. Now i want to check, whether the data is empty, then it shouldn't create the table view section. so i want to check it before create the table view. Which means, if the data is not empty then should create a section, otherwise can't create a section. SO the table view section only depends on the data(Empty or Not).

Here my sample code,

```
 person = [[Person alloc] initWithPersonName:DictionaryValue]; // Passing the values via Dictionary.
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:person animated:YES];
```

In Person Class:

```
-(Person *) initWithPersonName:(NSMutableDictionary *) personDict  
{
  self.tableView.delegate = self;

      [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Person" owner:self options:nil];

       NSString *firstName = [personDict valueForKey:@"firstName"];

       NSString *lastName = [personDict valueForKey:@"lastName"];

       NSString *cityName = [personDict valueForKey:@"city"];

       NSString *stateName = [personDict valueForKey:@"state"];

       return self;
 }
```

I want to create the two sections,

```
                  section - 1 -- > [firstName, LastName];
                  section - 2 -- > [city, state];
```

How can i put those section values into the arrays. Is possible to create a single array to use both sections or Need to create a separate array for store the separate sections.

Suppose i get the empty value for any data, so it shouldn't create a table view section. What are the possibilities to achieve this? Please guide me.

Please give me any sample code or sample link.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement -numberOfSectionsInTableView:, -tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:, and -tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: in your UITableViewController subclass (create one if you don't already have one). The names are pretty self-explanatory. So you could do something like:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (section == 0) return @"Title of section 1";
    if (section == 1) return @"Title of section 2";
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // return the number of rows you've got based on the section index
}
```

That, I believe, will create the section headers regardless of whether you've got rows in them or not, but nothing will show beneath it. So it will be clear that a section is empty if it has no data. Make sense?

Cody

Comment: I have used all the properties of the table view. I want to know the table view section created which depends on the NSMutableDictionary data as dynamically. Thanks.

Comment: Could you try to rephrase that? I'm not clear on exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: My goal is, In the case of, firstName = @" " or nil, so that table section is created for - Section- 1 (Last Name) and Section - 2[city, state]. SO i should remove the first row for First Name. So it displayed only Last name in First Section and City, state is displayed in the second section. SO it depends on the data is empty or not. If the data is empty, then we should removed that row or section. Thanks

Comment: In my thought, i should check the data is empty or not, after that table view is created and allocated the number of sections or rows in the cell. Thanks.